# Можете посоветовать хорошие уроки по Laravel? Желательно интернет-магазин

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу написать интернет-магазин используя laraver. Нужны толковые уроки по нему, можно на английском языке. Сейчас я прошёл [эти уроки](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWdmR3tpvXkzubAZugUQLdw), но не достаточно для хорошего понимая. Или посоветуйте что-то другое, толковое, пожалуйста. Потому что в поиске куча ненужной информации и найти что-то стоящее, большая проблема.

Comment: официальные бесплатные курсы от ларавел. есть даже субтитры русские

Comment: @n.osennij. Ссылка есть у вас?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLl_kpL5cwH6LLuvd_xXOplXejM7shFhme&v=E7FQEutaCiQ
Вообще ищите и другие курсы от Laracasts. Есть и более продвинутые.

Comment: Просто тренируйтесь на реальном проекте (пусть даже он будет "для себя") - всё приходит с практикой. Что-то не понятно? Гуглим и читаем документацию.